# ASP.Net Web API sub folders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have FeatureA folder under my root folder (i.e. http://www.MyCompanyName.Come/FeatureA) that will hold several controllers under it:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "FeatureA",
              routeTemplate: "FeatureA/api/{controller}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Does my controller will be named HomeFeatureAController, by convention?**

Please tell me how to write a controller for FeatureA Home Page and other controllers under it.

FYI: I have the following folder structure:

Views>

.. Home>

.. .. Index.chtml

.. .. FeatureA>

.. .. .. Index.chtml

## UPDATE:

I found a great article recommending me to move Features (e.g. FeatureA) sub systems to MVC Areas. I will try the solution in this article:
http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/

Comment: I would also recommend using MVC Areas. Please make sure to add this as the answer if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC Areas is the easiest solution to partition any project. Meanwhile, Web API can get benefits from areas using the solution provided here: http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/

I wish I could use subfolders that reflect URLs when building bigger solutions.

Comment: So you created an Area within your controller folder (within WebAPI) ?

Comment: I find it strange you can't simply have Folders divvying up the controller folder...